# Android ViewPager not showed on screen inside ScrollView

Tags: android, android-viewpager

> I create a ViewPager dynamically :

```
private View createCarousel(Context context)
{
    ViewPager pager = new ViewPager(context);
    ArrayList<Drawable> drawables = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] carouselImages = mDisplayedGame.getCarouselImages();
    if (carouselImages != null) {
        for (String s : carouselImages) {
            drawables.add(ImageLoader.getInstance().getDrawable(s));
        }
        pager.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(context, drawables));
        pager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }
    return pager;
}
```

> Note: carouselImages != null always and `ImageLoader` works correctly.

### Adapter :

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter
{
    Context context;
    private ArrayList<Drawable> mDrawables;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Drawable> drawables, float width)
    {
        this.context = context;
        mDrawables = drawables;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return mDrawables.size();
    }

    @Override
    public float getPageWidth(int position)
    {
        return 1f;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object)
    {
        return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
    {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(mDrawables.get(position));
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
    {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
}
```

> And add to container :

```
mRootView.addView(createCarousel(this), new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

And ViewPager not showed. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get any exceptions ?

Answer (score 0):

Confuse about this situation but magic happens in this line :

```
mRootView.addView(createCarousel(this), new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

when i change height to 100 :

```
mRootView.addView(createCarousel(this), new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100 ));
```

Content was appeared on screen.

> So problem in setting layout params.

In my case i need to display fullscreen images so i just calculate dimens when app start and set manually them to constructor params.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you forget to set layout params for child ImageViews ? How about try something like:

```html
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
imageView.setImageDrawable(mDrawables.get(position));
imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
return imageView;
```

Comment: this getting no effect to me.